# pushing client and server to github while client already has a git repo

Tags: git, github

I have a MERN app with a server and client folder. the client folder already has a git repository which was caused when I entered the command create-react app. I would like to push the contents of both folders ie client and server to my github. How would I go about doing this, because inside client there is already a git folder ?

Comment: Delete the problematic git folder?